# Accessing listview/arrayadapter from within button OnClick method

Tags: java, android, listview, onclick, android-arrayadapter

This may be a bit of a silly question, but I am having a bit of a hard time understanding how to reference a listview/adapter that I created. I started by creating a custom listview that will allow me to display list items that have both pictures and text in them. I found a lot of great tutorials online, so this part wasn't too bad. I then added two buttons at the bottom of the listview that I would like to use to manipulate data within the listview. Now I can figure out how to access the list when I am in the `onItemClickListener` for the list, because you can simply call `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)` in order to access it. I am not quite sure how to access this list within the `onClick` method for the button, since the parent/position are not passed as parameters. So I suppose my first question is...

1. How to properly access the listview/arrayadapter I created from within my button `onClick` method.

The other question that I have been struggling with is how to search for an item (row) in my listview by  searching for the value of a specific element withing that row. For instance, in my code below, the rows I have created have five images, two text fields, and a boolean value. So how would I go about searching through my list to find the row that has the "address" of 555555, which corresponds to the Harley Davidson list entry.

I have included my code below. Thank you very much for the help.

**HelmetList.java**

```
public class HelmetList
{
    public HelmetList (String name, String address, String img_hel, String img_rec, String img_bat,
                            String img_dsk, String img_str, Boolean selected)
    {
        super();
        this.name       = name;
        this.address    = address;
        this.img_hel    = img_hel;
        this.img_rec    = img_rec;
        this.img_bat    = img_bat;
        this.img_dsk    = img_dsk;
        this.img_str    = img_str;
        this.selected   = selected;
    }

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String img_hel;
    private String img_rec;
    private String img_bat;
    private String img_dsk;
    private String img_str;
    private Boolean selected;

    public String getName ()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName (String s_name)
    {
        this.name = s_name;
    }

    public String getAddress ()
    {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress (String s_address)
    {
        this.address = s_address;
    }

    public String getImgHel ()
    {
        return img_hel;
    }

    public void setImgHel (String s_img_hel)
    {
        this.img_hel = s_img_hel;
    }

    public String getImgRec ()
    {
        return img_rec;
    }

    public void setImgRec (String s_img_rec)
    {
        this.img_rec = s_img_rec;
    }

    public String getImgBat ()
    {
        return img_bat;
    }

    public void setImgBat (String s_img_bat)
    {
        this.img_bat = s_img_bat;
    }

    public String getImgDsk ()
    {
        return img_dsk;
    }

    public void setImgDsk (String s_img_dsk)
    {
        this.img_dsk = s_img_dsk;
    }

    public String getImgStr ()
    {
        return img_str;
    }

    public void setImgStr (String s_img_str)
    {
        this.img_str = s_img_str;
    }

    public Boolean getSelected ()
    {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected (Boolean s_selected)
    {
        this.selected = s_selected;
    }
}
```

**HelmetListAdapter.java**

```
public class HelmetListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HelmetList>
{
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;

    public HelmetListAdapter (Context p_context, int p_resource, List<HelmetList> p_objects)
    {
        super (p_context, p_resource, p_objects);
        resource = p_resource;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from (p_context);
        context = p_context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        convertView = ( RelativeLayout ) inflater.inflate( resource, null );
        HelmetList Helmet = getItem (position);

        TextView hname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.h_name);
        hname.setText(Helmet.getName ());

        TextView haddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.h_address);
        haddress.setText(Helmet.getAddress ());

        ImageView himage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.h_image);
        String uri = "drawable/" + Helmet.getImgHel();
        int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, context.getPackageName());
        Drawable image = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
        himage.setImageDrawable(image);

        ImageView hrec = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.h_rec);
        uri = "drawable/" + Helmet.getImgRec();
        imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, context.getPackageName());
        image = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
        hrec.setImageDrawable(image);

        ImageView hlbat = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.h_lb);
        uri = "drawable/" + Helmet.getImgBat();
        imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, context.getPackageName());
        image = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
        hlbat.setImageDrawable(image);

        ImageView hldsk = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.h_ld);
        uri = "drawable/" + Helmet.getImgDsk();
        imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, context.getPackageName());
        image = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
        hldsk.setImageDrawable(image);

        ImageView hstr = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.h_str);
        uri = "drawable/" + Helmet.getImgStr();
        imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, context.getPackageName());
        image = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
        hstr.setImageDrawable(image);

        return convertView;

    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private ListView lvhelmets;
    private HelmetListAdapter adhelmets;
    private Context ctx;
    List<Integer> selected;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ctx = this;

        List<HelmetList> helmetlist = new ArrayList<HelmetList>();
        helmetlist.add(new HelmetList("Bell", "11111", "helmetpic0", "rec",
                "bat", "mm", "str", Boolean.FALSE));
        helmetlist.add(new HelmetList("Shoei", "33333", "helmetpic1", "rec",
                                        "bat", "mm", "str", Boolean.FALSE));
        helmetlist.add(new HelmetList("Harley Davidson", "55555", "helmetpic2", "rec",
                                        "bat", "mm", "str", Boolean.FALSE));
        helmetlist.add(new HelmetList("Joe Rocket", "77777", "helmetpic3", "rec",
                "bat", "mm", "str", Boolean.FALSE));


        lvhelmets = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Helmet_list);
        lvhelmets.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        adhelmets = new HelmetListAdapter(ctx, R.layout.row_format, helmetlist);
        lvhelmets.setAdapter (adhelmets);

        Button price = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPrice);
        Button safety = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSafety);

        price.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "price", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        safety.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "safety", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });



        lvhelmets.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                HelmetList helmet = (HelmetList) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                if (!helmet.getSelected())
                {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                    helmet.setSelected(Boolean.TRUE);
                }
                else
                {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    helmet.setSelected(Boolean.FALSE);
                }
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/Helmet_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnHolderLL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bPrice"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingRight="1dp"
            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="#222222"
            android:text="Price"
            android:clickable="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bSafety"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingRight="1dp"
            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="#222222"
            android:text="Safety"
            android:clickable="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**row_format.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <!--  ListRow Left side Thumbnail image -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/h_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/h_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/h_address"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/h_name"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="12dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"  />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/h_rec"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/h_lb"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/h_ld"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="85dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/h_str"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="125dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `onClick` method, try:

```
lvhelmets.setAdapter(new HelmetListAdapter(ctx, rowf_format.xml, helmetList));
```

That will call your adapter which will populate the `listview`.

Comment: Okay I got that part. Now how do I go about accessing an actual row? For instance how would I execute `.setSelected(Boolean.TRUE)` for a specific row?

Comment: Okay nevermind silly question I figured it out -> `HelmetList helmet = (HelmetList) lvhelmets.getItemAtPosition(0);`... But this causes some strange behaviour. As is visible in the code above, I am simply changing the background of the row and then calling `setSelected(Boolean.TRUE);` to note that a row is selected. When I modify a row property from within the button `onClick` the grey row highlighting disappears. Do you have any idea perhaps why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

If the List of Integers is meant to hold the indexes of selected items, then in your ListViews onItemClicked listener, add the position to your List of Integers when one is selected.

Make your List of HelmetLists a field in your Activity. That way, when you press either of the two buttons, you have both the index (es) of the HelmetList you need, as well as the list you can retrieve each object from. Wasn't sure in your scenario if you were allowing multi-selection.